# What are the noteworthy differences between an inverting and non-inverting op amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier

It seems like they both have the same ideal rules except that non-inverting op-amps are used more often. So what are the important differences between them?

Comment: "non-inverting op-amps are used more often" actually I'd argue it's the other way around.

Comment: Well not according to my book and professor, but that's a moot point that doesn't actually address anything useful.

Comment: Inverting Op-amps have a more linear amplification (assuming open loop gain is VERY large), which is important if you only need a moderate gain. So in cases that the 180° phase is not important, it is preferred.

Comment: I assume you mean "op amp circuits" rather than "op amps". Op amps themselves are neither inverting nor non-inverting.

Comment: What @Dehbop said, but the other big difference is the input impedance.

Comment: Common mode input doesn't swing with the inverting topology but does for non inverting.

Answer (score 4):

An inverting op-amp configuration can both **amplify** and **attenuate** a signal.

On the other hand a non-inverting configuration can **only amplify**.

**Inverting Configuration :**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fghVeJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

```
voltage gain = - Rf/R1
```

so resistor values can be selected to get any value of gain even *less than 1 (attenuation)*

**Non-inverting Configuration :**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwrQ2O.png)</sup>

```
voltage gain = 1 + Rf/R1
```

So, voltage gain value can never be *less than 1*

**Also input impedance value is much higher for a non-inverting configuration.**

Comment: There is one other thing too: so inverting op amps ideally have no input current, but does that also mean they have no output current? And how does this rule change between inverting and non-inverting if at all?

Comment: Both inverting and non-inverting configurations have very low output resistance. so you can draw a good amount of current from the op-amp output. One thing to notice here is that there is no relation between the input and output current for an op-amp.

Answer (score 1):

Decades ago I had the opportunity to change jobs, to a company needing me to come learn the circuitry methods for Inertial Navigation Systems. I choose to work elsewhere, but I've always wondered "what secrets of precision design" I would have learned.

Here is one secret of precision design I recently discovered: Inverting Config has *no* current flowing in the GND plane; NonInverting Config has the resistive divider current flowing in the GND plane.

Suppose you have 1mA in the Resistiver Divider (for low Boltsmann noise) and you have 10 squares of foil resistance (10 * 0.0005 ohms = 5 milliOhms) in the GND plane. You have 5 microVolts error, becomes maximum for large Vinput, thus its a GAIN error; you can calibrate this error, but the Rfoil is highly temperature sensitive (0.4% per degree C for copper foil). Thus the INS system needs to be temperature-stabilized.

And indeed the F4 Phantom INS was temperature-stabilized. Took 15 minutes on the flight line, to heat up and stabilize.

Thus somewhere in 16 bit region, certainly for 20 bits (5 uV/5volt) and 24 bits (300 nanoVolt / 5 volts), this seemingly trivial topological design choice affects the system design (yes or no on temperature control).